# How to integrate Data Factory with private GitHub repo

Tags: azure, github, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get a Data Factory code repository working on GitHub from within the Azure Portal.

When I enter my organization's name, I can only list the public repositories. How do I use a private repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Data Factory not having access. A co-worker later went through the same process and got a popup within Azure Portal that allowed them to give Data Factory access to the private repos. Not sure why they got the dialog popup but I didn't.

This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than check the "Enable GIT" box on the creation blade, leave the box unchecked, click through, then follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-visually#author-with-github-integration) by clicking the "Author & Monitor" hyperlink on the Overview blade to launch your data factory.

[image]

Comment: This is actually the process I was using (it's not an enterprise account though, so I left it unchecked). A co-worker went through the same process and got a popup that allowed them to give Data Factory access to the private repos. Not sure why they got the dialog popup but I didn't.

Comment: I would try again in an Incognito window incase you're logged into multiple accounts. Also, do you have r/w access to the repo?

Comment: I do have r/w access (same privileges as my co-worker) but, I didn't think about trying an incognito window. Regardless, my co-worker's actions allowed me to see private repos. This was also very close to an Azure outage so that may have been a factor too?